# How to run gulp command from package script start and build

Tags: angular, gulp

1. **Hi,I need to run gulp command via npm start.**
2. when I run gulp with command it's working but I need to run command
   automatically via npm start or ng build command

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cfch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "gulp && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", //it's working
    "build": "gulp && ng build --prod–aot && tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz dist/prod/*", //not working while type command ng build
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
   "dependencies": {
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install gulp as a Dev dependency. Then add gulp commands to start with &&. For an example

"start" : "gulp < command > && ng serve"

Comment: I tried to add script     "start": "ng serve && gulp  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", but won't running gulp  after type npm start.

Comment: I think more correct script would be "gulp <command>&& ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

Comment: yes , thanks it's working:"start": "gulp && ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", but build not working I have tried like that :"build": "gulp && ng build  --prod–aot

Comment: In that case I guess you can add a prebuild. example : "prebuild": "gulp"

Comment: Is there input command will be change ? but I need to use "ng build" . 1."prebuild": "gulp" 2."build": "gulp && ng build --prod–aot",